# Rpy2: how do I use the function 'as' (r library methods) in python?

Tags: python, pyqgis, r, kriging, rpy2

I want to coerce an object of class *Raster Layer* to class *SpatialPixelsDataFrame* since that is required as input for the function autoKrige from the r library automap.
However, when I try to use *as* from the r library methods, I get the following error:

```
Encountered "as" at line 307, column 25. Was expecting one of ...
```

Where line 307 is:

```
layerGrid = methods.as(layerRaster, "SpatialPixels")
```

I'm assuming that the word as has already has a meaning in python. The question is, however, how do I use the function as. Is it possibly replaced by rpy2 with a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing R symbols in packages that are syntactically invalid in Python can be done through `__dict__`. Here:

```
r_as = methods.__dict__['as']
```

See the documentation for rpy2: http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-r-packages

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around, store the R function in a separate function:

```
        robject.r('''setAs<-function(rasterAs){
                    asRaster <<- as(rasterAs, "SpatialPixels")
        }''')
```

Retrieve the function from the R global environment and call it:

```
        setAs = r.globalenv['setAs']
        SpatialPixels = setAs(layerRaster)
```